# db string length errors and NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

In a SQL server db I have a Name column in the Departments table, with nvchar(25) not null, unique. I test to see what happens if I try and save a Department with a Name that is bigger than that and get an "NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException" making it clear that ""String or binary data would be truncated". So far, so good.

In another table I have a Description column in a Projects table, with nvchar(50) not null, but doesn't have the unique constraint. I put it through the exact same test (of course making sure that the Description is bigger than 50), but no exception is thrown...

I prefer the very clear exception, but I'll settle for understanding what the rules are. Also how specific do NHib exceptions tend to be across different db's. What am I missing?

Cheers,
Berryl

## ANSWER

My fault! I was using a test fixture that used SqlLite instead of SqlServer. This is one of the reasons I stopped using SqlLite in the first place (there must be a reason why so many smart people seem to love it, but it's useless for verifying nhibernate mapping IMO).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is controlled by the [ANSI WARNINGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx) option:

> if an INSERT or UPDATE is tried on a
>   character, Unicode, or binary column
>   in which the length of a new value
>   exceeds the maximum size of the column

The option is a per database option.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are issued by MS SQL Server, not nHibernate. You should try running some queries directly using SQL Server Management Studio to determine what's going on.

Comment: Is there a particular query you have in mind to flesh this out?